# register_sidebar_widget is deprecated since version 2.8

Tags: sidebar

I have an elderly WordPress theme that I am trying to bring back up to date.  I am stuck on the following snippet...

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar_widget') )
    register_sidebar_widget(__('Pages'), 'widget_nav');
```

This is giving me the following message...

register_sidebar_widget is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_sidebar_widget() instead

I realise that reigster_sidebar_widget has now been replaced by wp_register_sidebar_widget() but I can't work out whats changed with the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...

```
register_sidebar_widget( $name, $output_callback, $classname );
```

vs.

```
wp_register_sidebar_widget( $id, $name, $output_callback, $options, $params, ... );
```

It is simple enough to check the Codex entries for each:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar_widget
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_sidebar_widget

Beyond that, I am not quite sure what the question is. You might want to look into the [`register_widget`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget) function instead of either of those, though.